# How do you say "a sign that" as in "That is *a sign that* your rabbit loves you."?

Tags: syntax

How do you say "*a sign that*" as in "*That is **a sign that** your rabbit loves you.*"?

Would it be "*Id est signum **quod** tuus cuniculus te amet.*"? Or "*Id est signum **ut** tuus cuniculus te amet.*"? Or "*Id est signum tui cuniculi te ama**ndi**.*" (the gerund going in the genitive case)? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lewis & Short list in their dictionary under *signum* [this example](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0010%3Atext%3DS.%20Rosc.%3Achapter%3D30) from Cicero:

> neque enim id facerem, nisi necesse esset, **et id erit signi me invitum facere**, quod non persequar longius quam salus huius et mea fides postulabit.

> And I would not do even that if it were not necessary, **and it shall be a sign that I am doing it against my will**, that I will not pursue the point further than the safety of Roscius and my own good faith requires. translation: C. D. Yonge).

So a possible formula is here given: *id est signi + acc+inf*.

Also, in Exodus 3:12 we can have another example ("And this will be the sign to you that it is I who have sent you") which the Vulgate renders with **quod**:

> et hoc habebis signum, quod miserim te: cum eduxeri ...

[So *quod* was indeed used; however, it might be little "annoying" as *signum* is already of neutral gender so in *signum quod*, *quod* can open also a relative clause    (Cf. Cicero: *Signum est quod sub sensum aliquem cadit et quiddam significat quod ex ipso profectum videtur* - "A sign is *which* ..."]

Alternative translation by Sebastian Castellio which is known in its Ciceronian style - indeed [mimics](https://books.google.com/books?id=F37WbhXd-cUC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22a%20me%20te%20esse%20missum%22&source=bl&ots=BOQTw7FFsf&sig=ACfU3U23HTOaEOqeyG6yN5wswLgB7Cc3kg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE8uW31v_-AhUZwAIHHa3HADQQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22a%20me%20te%20esse%20missum%22&f=false) Cicero here:

> atque hoc erit signi, a me te esse missum, quod ...

I would avoid using *signum ut* here, as using *ut* will naturally and reasonably imply the *purpose* of a sign (not its *meaning*). We have example for this purposintial  sense usage of *ut* in Genesis 4:15 *Posuitque Dominus Cain signum, ut non interficeret eum omnis qui invenisset eum.*

I'm not sure about the genitive usage. There are examples the genitive was also used as purpose (*Signum proelii committendi Caesar dedit*) or more accurately and simply it answer *which* sign? (e.g., sign of the singing roosters (*dicere deos gallis signum dedisse   cantandi*); it describes the sign itself - which sign is it; and not quite what a sign signifies. But maybe there are other examples as well.